# How to add a child node in xml?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

i have the following xml. i want to add the value of 22. i just tried the insertXMLafter; but, its not working.

`

```
<XML>
    <FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
    <FRUITS>
        <FRUIT>
            <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
            <ORANGE_FIELDS>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                    <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                </FIELD>
            </ORANGE_FIELDS>
        </FRUIT>
    </FRUITS>
```

`

```
My expectation is 

    `<XML>
<FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
<FRUITS>
    <FRUIT>
        <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
        <ORANGE_FIELDS>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                <VALUE>22</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
        </ORANGE_FIELDS>
    </FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
```

`

please guide me to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERTCHILDXML` as before along with `FIELD[KEY="WEIGHT"]` to indicate the `FIELD` node in which you need insertion.

```
WITH t ( old_xml, child_xml, node, field_name) AS
      ( SELECT 
    '<XML>
        <FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
    <FRUITS>
        <FRUIT>
            <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
            <ORANGE_FIELDS>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                    <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                </FIELD>
            </ORANGE_FIELDS>
        </FRUIT>
    </FRUITS>
    </XML>
    ' old_xml,

    '<VALUE>22</VALUE>' child_xml,

      '/XML/FRUITS/FRUIT/ORANGE_FIELDS/FIELD[KEY="WEIGHT"]' node,
               'VALUE' field_name
       FROM dual)
SELECT
  INSERTCHILDXML(XMLTYPE(old_xml),
  node,
  field_name,
  XMLTYPE(child_xml))
FROM t;
```

Comment: Actually Thanks. But i want to handle the child node dynamically. That means i want to add the <VALUE>22</VALUE> for which FIELD have the KEY as WEIGHT. Could you please...

Comment: @AzhagiriS : Edited. Pls check.

Answer (score 0):

`insertXmlAfter` is depracated from oralce 11g. Here is a page with good description how to replace old approach with new. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6044

Example:

```
select xmlserialize(document xmlquery('copy $tmp := $doc modify (
  for $row in $tmp/XML/FRUITS/FRUIT/ORANGE_FIELDS/FIELD
  where not(exists($row/VALUE))
  return insert node    <VALUE>{$value}</VALUE> into $row 
  )
return $tmp'
                passing xmltype('<XML>
    <FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
    <FRUITS>
        <FRUIT>
            <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
            <ORANGE_FIELDS>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                    <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                </FIELD>
            </ORANGE_FIELDS>
        </FRUIT>
    </FRUITS>
    </XML>') as "doc", 'xxxx' as "value" returning content) as clob)
  from dual;
```

In example i'm using two structure CMR (copy/modify/return) and FLWOR(for/let/where/order/return)